# Saving Excel Worksheet as a Read Only PDF File?

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint-2010

I have a report that is built off of an excel macro that is triggered when the file is opened.  I use a Windows Scheduled Task to open the file which triggers the macro and then closes the file.

As part of the process within this marco one of the worksheets is saved as PDF file to our network.  This file is then linked to through our sharepoint site.  It appears that if someone is viewing this pdf and the macro is triggered it doesn't update the PDF File since it is opened. I am handling this error by saving a backup file to a different folder with a different name.

I'm trying to find a good way to work around this.  Is there a way to export and save the PDF as read only through the excel vba? Is there a setting in Sharepoint that would make the file open as Read Only?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Changing an attribute in excel vba can be done using `SetAttr`, please see the following link: [link](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/setattr.php)

Comment: Thanks for that note.  I can see myself using that in the future.  Unfortunately it isn't resolving the issue I'm having with this particular project.  I have run into the oddest errors with this.  I have this process triggered by a Batch file through a scheduled task.  If the PDF file i'm updating is opened when I trigger this through my local computer the PDF file is updated no problem.  When I trigger the Batch file on my Virtual Machine with a different User Profile it throws a 'File Open...' Error.  Is it possible that the ability to update that file is linked to the user profile?

Comment: Although we use Virtual Machines at my company, I have not experienced a problem setting the attribute from different machines\user ids.  But sorry, I cannot speak with authority to your question.  Perhaps stating the obvious, but the PDF file should be closed when SetAttr is run.  Is it possible that the batch file has it open while it is attempting to change its attribute?

Comment: Hmm...that is interesting. I'll check to see.  Thanks for that.